# Count selected cells, rows and columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to see the stats on the selected cells (does not matter the value), rows and columns in Excel?

[image]

```
Selected
- cells: 6
- rows: 2
- columns: 3
```

Comment: There is unfortunately no way to do this in Excel without using VBA coding. With VBA you can code a simple UDF that will return the summary info you want. See i.e. here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080741/get-user-selected-range) to get you started.

Comment: You would have to hard-code the range into the formula, eg: `=rows(b2:d3)` => `2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While selecting a range of cells in Excel (even by dragging with mouse or holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>arrow key</kbd>s, you can see rows and columns count left to the formula box, as in the picture.

When dragging by mouse, hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> it makes you can see the number of rows and columns even after you stop dragging the selection with the mouse.

If all cells you want to count have a value inside, you can see the number in the status bar (when you have checked "count" (right click on status bar to make settings))

If you have empty or mixed selection, you can select, write something (it will go in the active cell) and press CTRL+Enter to fill all cells with that value. Then you read the amount of cells and Undo.

[image]

[image]

Write for example "my selection" and press CTRL+Enter

[image]
[image]

Then undo (CTRL+Z), to go back to your original data.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Note this works only while dragging or hold shift.

Comment: please add the remark  to explanation that about pressing the buttons to see such a result for completeness.

Comment: To augment this solution: You can select all the required cells, press `F2`, type `1` and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` which would fill all the cells with 1's. The count bottom right will provide the total number of cells. If the cells contained useful data, just immediately hit `CTRL+z` to undo.

Comment: @ExcelEverything, interesting approach, I didn't know about Ctrl+Shift+Enter :) ... however, all your suggestions mean to modify the spreadsheet. The OP wants just to count them

Comment: @ExcelEverything better just press CTRL+Enter because then it even will fill cells which are not connected with each other. No need to press F2.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this without VBA, well sort of. It requires one additional step, and that is to bold your selected data. The method below will count all bolded cells in a define range:

1. Define a named range *IsBold* as `=LAMBDA(r, GET.CELL(20,r))`
2. Use this formula to count the max columns `=MAX(BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r, SUM(BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,--IsBold(c)))))))+RAND()*0`
3. Use this formula to count the max rows `=MAX(BYCOL(data,LAMBDA(r, SUM(BYROW(r,LAMBDA(c,--IsBold(c)))))))+RAND()*0`
4. Use this formula to count the number of bold cells `=SUM(BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r, SUM(BYCOL(r,LAMBDA(c,--IsBold(c)))))))+RAND()*0`

Where *data* is e.g. $A$1:$F$24.

Requirements:

- Must have Office 365 for the newer array functions used.
- Save the file as a macro-enabled .xlsm file in order for GET.CELL function to work
- Hit F9 to refresh to calculation after changing the bold formatting (FYI, changing formatting is non-volatile and would not trigger an automatic recalculation - this is why the RAND()*0 is added, to make the formulae volatile and force Excel to recalculate).

Comment: I don't really understood all this... I open a new excel, highlight some cells, I have no data at all... what are all that steps, what should I bold?

Comment: what if some of my data are already in bold... and/or should not be modified?

Comment: You can still bold blank cells and the formulae would still work. For blanks cells, there is also a much simpler solution, which I'll comment on Prema's solution to get the cell count. For the case where you already have bold cells, you can alter the solution slightly to rather work with the fill colour by defining *IsFilled* as `=LAMBDA(r, GET.CELL(63,r))<>0`, and replace all *IsBold* functions with *IsFilled*. Now instead of bolding, fill the selected cells with say a red background colour. The formulae above with count the three values required for cell, row and column counts.